# Period in list of numbers?

Tags: punctuation

A319: 200km

B737: 400km

vs

A319: 200km.

B737: 400km.

Which is correct? Period or no period in a bullet point list of numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a period unless the bullet points were full sentences. Also most style guides recommend a space, or a "thin space" between the value and the unit, so "400 km" not "400km". A thin space is the official SI standard, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

As David Siegel mentioned above, the bullet points are not full sentences in this case, and you do not need to use period. Instead of this, you can put a semicolon at the end of each row (and use a period at the end of the last item) - you will keep the continuity of the list then. Some writers consider that it is not the best business writing choice, so you may just skip periods.